# Has anyone gotten a ruby memcached client working on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, memcached

Google'd around.  Getting stuck on installing libmemcached.

**UPDATE:**
***This is the new error log for Ruby 1.9.3***

```
checking for pthread-config... no
configure: error: could not find libpthread
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:35:in `run': 'env CFLAGS='-fPIC  -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-
        from extconf.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in check_libmemcached'
        from extconf.rb:52:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:52:in `block in check_libmemcached'
        from extconf.rb:49:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:49:in `check_libmemcached'
        from extconf.rb:70:in `<main>'
Touching aclocal.m4 in libmemcached.
touch -r libmemcached-0.32/m4/visibility.m4 libmemcached-0.32/configure.ac libmemcache
Configuring libmemcached.
env CFLAGS='-fPIC  -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-lon
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/memcached-1.3.5
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/memcached-1.3.5/ext/gem_make.out
```

My installation is Ruby 1.8.7 from rubyinstaller.org. (mingw32 version)
Installed Northscale/membase (membase.org).  Installed fine.

Then tried both

gem install memcached-northscale --no-ri --no-rdoc
and 
gem install memcached --no-ri --no-rdoc

Both of them want to install libmemcached and build from source... OK..

C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Building libmemcached.
tar xzf libmemcached-0.32.tar.gz 2>&1
Patching libmemcached source.
patch -p1 -Z < libmemcached.patch
patching file libmemcached-0.32/libmemcached/memcached_response.c
Assertion failed: hunk, file ../patch-2.5.9-src/patch.c, line 354

This URL suggested a fix .. Windows handling of CR/CRLF.

http://www.mail-archive.com/gnuwin32-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01528.html

But despite altering the .patch files, I still get a failure:

C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\memcached-northscale-0.19.5.4\ext>ruby extconf.rb
Building libmemcached.
tar xzf libmemcached-0.32.tar.gz 2>&1
Patching libmemcached source.
patch -p1 -Z < libmemcached.patch
[... snip ...]
Patching libmemcached with SASL support.
patch -p1 -Z < sasl.patch
[... snip ...]
The next patch would create the file libmemcached-0.32/config/config.rpath,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file libmemcached-0.32/config/config.rpath.rej
patching file libmemcached-0.32/config.h.in
patching file libmemcached-0.32/configure
patch: **** malformed patch at line 26625: '

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Any ideas?  Surely someone out there uses Windows, Ruby, and Memcache???

Comment: Answering my own question: I'm sort of unblocked, since I was able to install memcache-client.  But I'm wondering whether anyone else has been able to install one of the Pure C library clients.

Answer (score 1):

The libmemcached support for Windows is in its infancy.  Generally, people use a ruby native client on Windows, just as you've found.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. Install MemCached win32 binary from http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/.

direct download link:

http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin.zip

1. Install Memcached-Client

   ## gem install memcache-client
2. Start the memcached Server. It says Start the server from the Microsoft Management Console or by running the following command:

   'c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d start'